# How to set title of navigationitem which have titleview for some conditions

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, swrevealviewcontroller

I have a `navigationItem` with a `titleView`. Now in some conditions I want to use the `title` property for that `navigationItem`. How to do that? Any idea?

Here is what I have tried, however is not working:

```
self.revealViewController().navigationItem.titleView = UIView.init()

self.revealViewController().navigationItem.title = "My Item"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you set title, you need to set titleView to nil.

Answer (score 0):

In your `viewdidload` of your viewcontroller, you can set title something like,

```
  self.title = "your title"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIView* titleView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40)];
//titleView.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
```

self.navigationItem.titleView=titleView;